# How to set Arraylist of size > 10,000 to RecyclerView

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation());
         
    Adapter adapter= new Adapter (arrayList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

App Crashes when ArrayList Size became greater than 10,000.

This is the log

```
Background young concurrent copying GC freed 168778(4611KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(1088KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 17MB/22MB, paused 124us total 116.099ms
```

What is the correct method to set Huge ArrayList and Scroll Smoothly?

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: it shows this line Repeatedly - Background young concurrent copying GC freed 168922(4611KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(1088KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 17MB/22MB, paused 131us total 116.076ms

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to perform what you want to do is to implement pagination (load content on demand) to don't overtake all the app disponible ram.

If you are using ViewModel architecture take a look at the pagination component:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Pagination is a little complex concept, maybe you could follow a tutorial.